# I need to calculate percentage of tails/heads

Tags: python, list

I need to calculate percentage of tails/heads. I wrote a part of the code that works but not the way it should! the more heads or tails I get, the less chance they get! How can I solve the problem? Here is part of the code I wrote.

```
throws=[]
while True:
    throw=input("You flip the coin and it was?Head/Tail: ")
    throws.append(throw)
    total_flips=len(throws)
    heads_count=throw.count("head")
    tails_count = throw.count("tail")

    heads_percentage=(heads_count/total_flips)*100
    tails_percentage = (tails_count/total_flips) * 100
    match throw:
        case "head":
            print(f"Percent of head:{heads_percentage}%")
        case "tail":
            print(f"Percent of tail:{tails_percentage}%")
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `heads_count` and `tails_count` have the values you expect? See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should change below from "throw" to "throws" because count should work at the list

```
    heads_count = throws.count("head") # origin code "throw"
    tails_count = throws.count("tail") # origin code "throw"
```

Comment: There are two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I forgot to change the roll to rolls, thus I did not refer to the list:

```
heads_count = throws.count("head") # origin code "throw"
tails_count = throws.count("tail") # origin code "throw"
```